# Как сделать свою выборку в формате cifar-10?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, распознавание-образов

Я увлеклась созданием нейросетей, по урокам сделала сеть на выборке cifar-10. Но мне хочется, чтобы моя нейросеть распознавала другие объекты. У меня есть большой набор моих изображений, их все я уменьшила до 32х32.

Но как их сделать такого формата, как в cifar-10?

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-pre-trained-vgg-model-classify-objects-photographs/